# how to strpos with array or in_array in multiple text string

Tags: php, arrays, string, strpos

I made this code

```
$message = 'This domain has strpos';
$links = array('domain.com', 'do.main');
$safe = strpos($message, $links);
return $message;
```

but got error **errorHandler->error** in my page, whats wrong with my code?
did I do some missing code?

what I want  just detect if the message have string in $links then do rest of my code

thanks for droping out

Comment: The second argument of strpos is a string (or something that can be converted to a string), not an array.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php.  You need to loop on the array values (foreach) or use array_walk or array_map. 
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this one will give expected output.

```
$message = 'This domain has strpos';
$links = array('domain.com', 'do.main');
$safe = array();
foreach($links as $key=>$result){
    if(strpos($message, $result) != false){
      $safe[$result] = "String is available";   
    } else{
      $safe[$result] = "String is not available";       
    }

}
print_r($safe);
```

Comment: I would use `if(strpos($message, $result) !== false){ ... }`, otherwise you are testing for whether the string appears at the start of the 'haystack' variable, not whether it is present at all. See php.net's comment on evaluating booleans with strpos.

Answer (score 4):

Since PHP has no elegant solution and all I see is full blown functions here's a simple one that will work

$arr will hold an array of string you do NOT want

```
// If string has illegal characters return false 
function str_allowed($str, $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $bad_string) {
        if(strpos($str, $bad_string) !== false)
            return false; // bad string detected, return false
    }
    return true; // if we got this far means everything's good return true
}
```